# Is there any real root of the cubic polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

For a polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ can we show that it has atleast one real root where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Can we generalise and conclude the same thing about any polynomial of odd degree?

**Note:-** For a cubic polynomial we can say that it can have two complex roots which are conjugate and hence the third root can be real(I am unable to prove), but for any higher odd degree polynomial how can we assume that the conjugate complex roots exist like the case of cubic polynomial. Thank you.

Comment: It is sufficient to show $f(x)>0$ for some real $x$ and $f(x)<0$ for some real $x$. Then , you can imply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Alternatively , you use the fundamental theorem of algebra stating that we have exactly $deg(f)$ solutions (considering multiplicity) and the non-real solutions always appear in pairs (If $x+iy$ is a solution , then also $x-iy$) , so the number of real roots must be an odd number.

Comment: Yes, of course. In a polynomial function of any degree, the term with the highest degree will dominate the others for large enough values of $x$. If $a_n$ is the coefficient of this term (call it $x^n$), then when $a_n\gt 0$, there will a point to the left of $x=0$ at and after which the negative contribution of $x^n$ will exceed the contributions of all the other terms whether those be positive or negative, i.e. $f(x)\lt 0$, proving the existence of at least one real root. Similarly for the case $a_n\lt 0$.

Comment: put another way:  polynomila is $a x^n \left( 1 + \frac{c_1}{x}  +   \frac{c_2}{x^2}  +  \right)  $   where very large $|x|$   forces the amount in the parentheses  to be close to $1$  and therefore positive.  So, large $|x|,$  sign  (signum)  is that of $a x^n.$  Since $n$ is odd this is the sign of $ax$

Comment: Of course you need *all* coefficients to be real. I think you already know that the nonreal roots occur in conjugate pairs. That always leaves at least one to be real. Your argument is sufficient.